# Use ajax to fill cities in a dropdown in a  mvc based php application?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

In a PHP MVC application, the model part has a `city.php` file that defines a city class.

The city class has a method to fetch all cities for a province i.e.

```
getCitiesByProvince('ProvinceId')
```

When the user selects a province from a province dropdown, I need to make an ajax call to `getCitiesByProvince('ProvinceId')` depending upon what value for Province Id was selected by the user inside the Province dropdown.

How do I do this?

Edit: 1) The page uses the GET method and not the POST method.  2) The controller file uses a switch($action) to execute a specific case. For example to fetch all cities

```
 case 'cities': //Get all cities for  a provinceId
                $city= new city();
                $cities = $City->getCitiesByProvince('ProvinceId');
                echo json_encode($cities);
```

Action is probably a hidden html attribute that tells the php script what action/case to perform... maybe something like

```
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cities" />
```

This is another developer's code  that i'm not too familiar with at the moment and i'm just trying to guess how things work by looking into various files...

Comment: What have you tried? Plenty of other questions here on SO could answer this along with a Google search for "ajax fill dropdown based on another dropdown"

Comment: i searched here on stackoverflow before posting this... i did not find exactly what i was looking for... those questions either used ajax for procedural non-mvc code or were based on specific mvc frameworks such as CodeIgniter etc. which i don't understand...

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to call this straight from the model insted you'd need to make an action in the controller called getcities or whatever and use $.ajax or $.get or $.post or $.getJSON to retreve the results assuming they'd be in json format heres an example using $.post

if your controller is citycntrl.php inside the controller you would do

//whatever logic to get an array of cities in whatever format you'd like 
ex: '{zip}' => '{cityname}', or just {cityname} with regular keys

using the $_POST['providenceId']; key were sending with jQuery

What you'd want to do is run the array through json_encode($arrayname); and echo that out in your controller based on the providenceId post value.

Heres a better code example for your drop down senario i misread the first time and missed the drop down part

```
$.post('controller/getcities', {
    provinceId: $('#{dropdownIDorCLASS}:selected').val();
}, function (data) {
    //data will contain your list of cities passed down from your controller.
    //do whatever with returned json data
}, 'json');
```

if I'm just confusing the crap out of you feel free to contact me on Skype and i hopefully assist a bit better UN: fallen.networks

Comment: Well its very dependent on what MVC your using this was the most all encompassing way to phrase the answer if you could let me know what MVC your on i can give a direct answer

Comment: Proprietory/Custom mvc app... not using  mvc php frameworks existing in the market...  I don't have indepth knowledge of Ajax or json .. i just know ajax can do this for me and just a basic understanding of Ajaz... if this was plain php i wuldn't be even asking this question here on So as there are plenty of examples for plain php such as  req.open("GET", findState.php?country="+countryId;
 true);

Comment: ok if i had a reference to a city object such as $city = new city(); what do i actually need to do to achieve something similar to req.open("GET.....) in terms of calling a class method such as req.open("GET",$city->getCitiesByProvince('ProvinceId')

Comment: i can make this call inside the controller as you said.... say the controler file is citycntrl.php

Comment: I don't know/understand JSON so plain javascript/ajax is helpful or otherwise if you believe JSON example is easily understandable then JSON might be fine as well...

Comment: i edited my question to add some more information. Please have a look at the question again.  Also for  provinceId: $('#{dropdownIDorCLASS}:selected').val(); considering the name for the region dropdown   i.e <select name=region> is region, should i do something like  $('#{region}:selected').val()  I suppose i'm beginning to understand a bit of JSON/Jquery now (just read a couple of quick tutorials) and perhaps we're close to a solution to this :)

Answer (score 1):

Have your PHP file do the following:

```
<?php
$province = $_GET['p'];

$cities = array();
$city_results = ... // fetch cities from database

foreach($city_results as $city_result) {
    $cities[] = $city_result->city;
}

echo json_encode($cities);
?>
```

Have your Javascript do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php_url_path",
    data: { p: get_province_here() },
    success: function (cities) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            ... // handle options here
        }
    }
});
```

This will create the inter-file connection that you seek. Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: 1)Considering  <select name=region> how would you get a value for the region dropdown so that i could replace the data: { p: get_province_here() } block  ?   2)  url: "php_url_path", can i do something like url:"ABSOLUTE_PATH/citycntrl.php"  where "ABSOLUTE_PATH is a constant that defines the root directory of the script where the citycntrl.php file resides?  citycntrl.php is the php controller file that calls the method to fetch the cities...